# SciKit-Learn Interactive simulation of data through UI

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, tk-toolkit

With the current version 0.22.2 there is a interactive tool to enter interactive data and see the results. Its called Libsvm GUI. 
I never managed to have it running in Jupyter notebook. 
Having seen that there is a binder option. When trying this (which should not depend on my computer environment) errors come up.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/svm_gui.html

```
Automatically created module for IPython interactive environment
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e5e1b6a6b155> in <module>
      6 
      7 import matplotlib
----> 8 matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
      9 
     10 from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305                 f"for the old name will be dropped %(removal)s.")
    306             kwargs[new] = kwargs.pop(old)
--> 307         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    308 
    309     # wrapper() must keep the same documented signature as func(): if we

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in use(backend, warn, force)
   1305         if force:
   1306             from matplotlib.pyplot import switch_backend
-> 1307             switch_backend(name)
   1308     else:
   1309         # Finally if pyplot is not imported update both rcParams and

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in switch_backend(newbackend)
    234                 "Cannot load backend {!r} which requires the {!r} interactive "
    235                 "framework, as {!r} is currently running".format(
--> 236                     newbackend, required_framework, current_framework))
    237 
    238     rcParams['backend'] = rcParamsDefault['backend'] = newbackend

ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

Seeing the first error, it seems even with the untouched binder environment there is something wrong. But I am not sure if it is with binder or with the code itself.

What can I try to make it working?